# Best way to combine similar SQL tables into more generic tables (without losing information/ efficiency)

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm currently trying to figuring out the best way to store data in my database. Right now I have the following schema:

```
GAME (id)
HAND (id, game_id)
GAME_SLOT (id, game_id, position) unique on game_id and position
HAND_SLOT (id, hand_id, position) unique on hand_id and position
GAME_SLOT_CARD (id, game_slot_id, card_id, next_game_slot_card_id [nullable], prev_game_slot_card_id [nullable])
HAND_SLOT_CARD (id, hand_slot_id, card_id, next_hand_slot_card_id [nullable], prev_hand_slot_card_id [nullable])
CARD (id)
```

Since my `GAME_SLOT`/ `HAND_SLOT` and `GAME_SLOT_CARD`/ `HAND_SLOT_CARD` tables share a similar structure I was hoping to combine them into the following schema:

```
GAME (id)
HAND (id, game_id)
SLOT (id, type, game_id [nullable], hand_id [nullable], position) unique on (type, game_id, position) and (type, hand_id, position)
SLOT_CARD (id, game_slot_id, card_id, next_slot_card_id [nullable], prev_slot_card_id [nullable])
CARD (id)
```

However, I was worried that this might cause me to lose some important information and might be considered bad practice. For example, I don't know if it is possible to enforce `SLOT` to have `game_id` if `type` is equal to 'slot' and visa versa. Or if I can add a constraint were if `SLOT.game_id` is `NOT NULL` then `SLOT.hand_id` must be `NULL`. Does anyone have any advice, is structuring my data like this okay? Or will it cause querying to be less efficient/ more prone to error.

Comment: What are you goals from this? From my perspective this isn't going to give you any benefits and as you are already discovering it's going to cause headaches.

Comment: My goal is to remove duplicate functionality on my backend API or having to write generics.

Answer (score 0):

This is what check constraints are for:

```
ALTER TABLE slot ADD CHECK (
   game_id IS NOT NULL AND hand_id IS     NULL AND txpe = 'game' OR
   game_id IS     NULL AND hand_id IS NOT NULL AND type = 'hand'
);
```